# I want to add pseudo-element like before and after in tailwindcss but it's not showing?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, postcss, tailwind-in-js

I want to add **pseudo-element** like **before and after** in tailwindcss but there is no tutorial video on *YouTube*, so I try to read *tailwindcss official documentations*, but it's not working.
I did same  thing  that written  in the tailwindcss  doc.

## my HTML and  tailwind CSS tags.

```
        <p
            class="
              text-white
              after:content-['OUTLAW DOT OG'] after:ml-0.5 after:text-red-500
            "
          >
            OUTLAW DOT OG
          </p>
```

[image: tailwind doc images]

## my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "project-1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/tailwind.css -o ./public/style.css -w",
    "build-p" : "postcss ./src/tailwind.css -o ./public/style.css -w" 

  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.6"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use underscores `_` instead of spaces   :

```
<p class="text-white after:content-['OUTLAW_DOT_OG'] after:ml-0.5 after:text-red-500">
  OUTLAW DOT OG
</p>
```

Note that if you want to use underscores you can escape them with a backslash : `\_`

Comment: thanks and sorry for late reply